# BroadcastReceiver doesn't handle SMS received

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I want to update total messages i.e. count and date of last sms and last sms when new sms received. But its not happening, its happened only when I relaunch activity.

```
     getAll.clear();
        Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");

         c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, "date DESC");

            startManagingCursor(c);
            count = new String[c.getCount()];
            snippet = new String[c.getCount()];
          thread_id = new String[c.getCount()];

            String[] num=new String[c.getCount()];
         date=new String[c.getCount()];
         address=new String[c.getCount()];
          c.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) 
            {
                count[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("message_count"))
                        .toString();
                thread_id[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"))
                        .toString();
                snippet[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet"))
                        .toString();
                date[i]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"))
                        .toString();

                cur=getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, "thread_id = " + thread_id[i], null, null);
                startManagingCursor(cur);
                cur.moveToFirst();
                     num[i]=getContactName(this,cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
               address[i]=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
               getAll.add(count[i]+","+num[i]+","+snippet[i]);
               cur.moveToNext();

              c.moveToNext();

            }
            adapter = new HomeAdapter(this, R.layout.sms, getAll,date);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

BroadCast Reciever

```
        if (null != bndl)
              {
     //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                  Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bndl.get("pdus");

                  msg = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];  

                  for (int i=0; i<msg.length; i++){
                      msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);            
                      contentTitle=msg[i].getOriginatingAddress().toString();
                      //contentTitle = (String) DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yy:hh:mm a", new Date(msg[i].getTimestampMillis()));
                      contentText = msg[i].getMessageBody().toString();

                        }
                  }
```

I tried all methods but failed to update and don't know what to do now.  I been stuck on this problem from 6 hours.

Comment: Can you publish your logcat messages?

Comment: logcat don't show any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fella

```
void update() {
    getAll.clear();
    Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, "date DESC");

    startManagingCursor(c);
    count = new String[c.getCount()];
    snippet = new String[c.getCount()];
    thread_id = new String[c.getCount()];

    String[] num = new String[c.getCount()];
    date = new String[c.getCount()];
    address = new String[c.getCount()];
    c.moveToFirst();

    try {
        int i = 1;
        if (c.getCount() >= 1) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                if (i == 35) {
                    i = 35;
                }

                count[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("message_count")).toString();
                thread_id[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")).toString();
                snippet[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet"));
                date[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
                Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, "thread_id = " + thread_id[i], null, null);
                cur.moveToFirst();
                startManagingCursor(cur);
                try {
                    num[i] = getContactName(this, cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    address[i] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                getAll.add(count[i] + "," + num[i] + "," + snippet[i]);
                i++;
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter = new HomeAdapter(this, R.layout.sms, getAll, date);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: it crashed my app giving this error                                                                                    08-16 11:14:21.614: E/AndroidRuntime(13659): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-119038
08-16 11:14:21.614: E/AndroidRuntime(13659): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 11:14:21.614: E/AndroidRuntime(13659):  at com.example.sms_app.Home.DoSomeFunkyStuff(Home.java:157)
08-16 11:14:21.614: E/AndroidRuntime(13659):  at com.example.sms_app.Home.access$0(Home.java:134)
08-16 11:14:21.614: E/AndroidRuntime(13659):  at com.example.sms_app.Home$1.run(Home.java:121)

Comment: at that line i am callying DoSomeFunkyStuff() method

Comment: Debug the code, put a breakpoint at "getAll.clear();" Step over until you find the null value. getAll.clear()l might be the issue. Step through the code, step into your own functions then see what happens and where it goes wrong. You cant get a null while calling "DoSomeFunkyStuff()" unless you have not initiated the class correctly. is DoSomeFunkyStuff in your activity class?

Comment: yes i m calling it in the same activity class in which it is defined

Comment: without thread this code don't give null point exception.. and when i call this method onresume instead of oncreate...it update listview but activity hang

Comment: it hangs because something is null, compare your on create and on resume and see what the difference is... Something is null that needs recreating within the onResume code. Its impossible to know what is null without the full project code that I can test myself.

Comment: Upload the project as a zip file to somewhere like mediafire or google drive or skydrive, then post the link in here

Comment: add me on skype, username "apmartin1991" Error is on line "num[i] = getContactName(this,cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());"

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?224mzwm2fgt2sm2     logcat not posting ..character exceeds the limit